# Bigquery SQL: Convert table values using a key-value table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I have two tables. 
The first table contains the key-value data:

```
   Answer_Code |Fruit
   1           |Apple
   2           |Orange
   3           |Pear
   4           |Watermelon
```

The second table contains the data collected

```
   Participant|Fruit
   Aaa        |1
   Bbb        |2
   Ccc        |3
```

How can I join these tables so that the Fruit column in the second table will be replaced with the Fruit values in the first table?

```
   Participant|Fruit
   Aaa        |Apple
   Bbb        |Orange
   Ccc        |Watermelon
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*,
FROM [Table1] T1, 
JOIN [Table2] T2 ON T1.Fruit = T2.Fruit,
LIMIT 10;
```

I get the following error:

*ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name. Consider using Standard SQL .google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/), which allows non-equality JOINs and comparisons involving expressions and residual predicates.*

Further I cannot get UPDATE, SET to work on bigquery.

Comment: Use StandardSql!  That is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ON clause is incorrect
Instead of `ON T1.Fruit = T2.Fruit` you should have `ON T1.Answer_Code = T2.Fruit`
Also you have few extra commas in your query

Anyway, your query should look like below

```
SELECT T2.Participant, T1.Fruit
FROM [Table1] T1 
RIGHT JOIN [Table2] T2 ON T1.Answer_Code = T2.Fruit
LIMIT 10
```

It is also recommended to [`migrate`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) to BigQuery Standard SQL - Standard SQL is the preferred SQL dialect for querying data stored in BigQuery and also has multiple [`advantages`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#advantages_of_standard_sql) including [`DML`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax) so you can `get UPDATE, SET to work on BigQuery`

Comment: Great! Thanks so much!